# jdbc slow insertion into tables (Prepared Statements)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, minecraft

this is my first question here, so please don't freak out when I am asking something wrong ;)

I am running A Minecraft-Server Network and I use spigot, which is the Server software.
This runs on a linux Root-Server with 16GB and an Intel Xeon.

For Spigot you can code plugins simply using the API. No problem there since the API is made very simple.

My Problem:
I made a Stats system, which which you can see your stats on the different servers using mysql, so they are the same on every server.
The servers with this mysql plugin are having bad performance, and I really think it is coming from MySQL.
The servers have a TPS (Ticks-Per-Second) of 18-19, which ideally should be 20 to be lagfree.
I used prepared Statements.

Here is my MySQL class:

```
package Heroz.FFA.MySQL;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MySQL {
        private String HOST = "";
        private String DATABASE = "";
        private String USER = "";
        private String PASSWORD = "";
        private String TABLE = "";
        public static Connection con;

        public MySQL(String host, String database, String user, String password,
                        String table) {
                this.TABLE = table;
                this.HOST = host;
                this.DATABASE = database;
                this.USER = user;
                this.PASSWORD = password;
                startConnection();
        }

        public void startConnection() {
                try {
                        try {
                                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + this.HOST
                                        + ":3306/" + this.DATABASE, this.USER, this.PASSWORD);
                        System.out.println("MySQL Verbindung wurde hergestellt!");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public void stopConnection() {
                try {
                        if (con != null) {
                                con.close();
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public void update(String name) {
                try {
                        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(name);
                        st.executeUpdate(name);
                        st.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        startConnection();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public static boolean exists(String Spielername) {
                try {
                        PreparedStatement st = con
                                        .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM FFA WHERE Spielername = '"
                                                        + Spielername + "'");
                        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                        if (rs.next()) {
                                return rs.getString("Spielername") != null;
                        }
                        return false;
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return false;
        }

        public static int getKills(String Spielername) {
                int kills = 0;
                try {
                        PreparedStatement st = con
                                        .prepareStatement("SELECT Kills FROM FFA WHERE Spielername = '"
                                                        + Spielername + "'");
                        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                        if (rs.next()) {
                                kills = rs.getInt("Kills");
                        } else {
                                kills = 0;
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return kills;
        }

        public static int getTode(String Spielername) {
                int tode = 0;
                try {
                        PreparedStatement st = con
                                        .prepareStatement("SELECT Tode FROM FFA WHERE Spielername = '"
                                                        + Spielername + "'");
                        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                        if (rs.next()) {
                                tode = rs.getInt("Tode");
                        } else {
                                tode = 0;
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return tode;
        }

        public static void createPlayer(String Spielername) {
                try {
                        PreparedStatement x = con
                                        .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM FFA WHERE Spielername = '"
                                                        + Spielername + "';");
                        ResultSet rs = x.executeQuery();
                        if (!rs.next()) {
                                x.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO FFA(Spielername, Kills, Tode, Wins, Punkte, Gespielt) VALUES ('"
                                                + Spielername + "', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0');");
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public static void addTode(String Spielername, int karma) {
                try {
                        PreparedStatement x = con
                                        .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM FFA WHERE Spielername = '"
                                                        + Spielername + "'");
                        ResultSet rs = x.executeQuery();

                        int punkte = getTode(Spielername) + karma;
                        if (rs.next()) {
                                x.executeUpdate("UPDATE FFA SET Tode = '" + punkte
                                                + "' WHERE Spielername = '" + Spielername + "'");
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public static void addKills(String Spielername, int karma) {
                try {
                        PreparedStatement x = con
                                        .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM FFA WHERE Spielername = '"
                                                        + Spielername + "'");
                        ResultSet rs = x.executeQuery();

                        int punkte = getKills(Spielername) + karma;
                        if (rs.next()) {
                                x.executeUpdate("UPDATE FFA SET Kills = '" + punkte
                                                + "' WHERE Spielername = '" + Spielername + "'");
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public static int getWins(String Spielername) {
                int wins = 0;
                try {
                        PreparedStatement st = con
                                        .prepareStatement("SELECT Wins FROM FFA WHERE Spielername = '"
                                                        + Spielername + "'");
                        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                        if (rs.next()) {
                                wins = rs.getInt("Wins");
                        } else {
                                wins = 0;
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return wins;
        }

        public static void addWins(String Spielername, int zahl) {
                try {
                        if (exists(Spielername)) {
                                PreparedStatement x = con
                                                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM FFA WHERE Spielername = '"
                                                                + Spielername + "'");
                                ResultSet rs = x.executeQuery();

                                int punkte = getWins(Spielername) + zahl;
                                if (rs.next()) {
                                        x.executeUpdate("UPDATE FFA SET Wins = '" + punkte
                                                        + "' WHERE Spielername = '" + Spielername + "'");
                                }
                        } else {
                                System.out.println("§cFehler!");
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public static int getPunkte(String Spielername) {
                int punkte = 0;
                try {
                        PreparedStatement st = con
                                        .prepareStatement("SELECT Punkte FROM FFA WHERE Spielername = '"
                                                        + Spielername + "'");
                        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                        if (rs.next()) {
                                punkte = rs.getInt("Punkte");
                        } else {
                                punkte = 0;
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return punkte;
        }

        public static void addPunkte(String Spielername, int karma) {
                try {
                        PreparedStatement x = con
                                        .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM FFA WHERE Spielername = '"
                                                        + Spielername + "'");
                        ResultSet rs = x.executeQuery();

                        int punkte = getPunkte(Spielername) + karma;
                        if (rs.next()) {
                                x.executeUpdate("UPDATE FFA SET Punkte = '" + punkte
                                                + "' WHERE Spielername = '" + Spielername + "'");
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public static int getPlayed(String Spielername) {
                int gespielt = 0;
                try {
                        PreparedStatement st = con
                                        .prepareStatement("SELECT Gespielt FROM FFA WHERE Spielername = '"
                                                        + Spielername + "'");
                        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                        if (rs.next()) {
                                gespielt = rs.getInt("Gespielt");
                        } else {
                                gespielt = 0;
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return gespielt;
        }

        public static void addPlayed(String Spielername, int karma) {
                try {
                        PreparedStatement x = con
                                        .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM FFA WHERE Spielername = '"
                                                        + Spielername + "'");
                        ResultSet rs = x.executeQuery();

                        int punkte = getPlayed(Spielername) + karma;
                        if (rs.next()) {
                                x.executeUpdate("UPDATE FFA SET Gespielt = '" + punkte
                                                + "' WHERE Spielername = '" + Spielername + "'");
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

How can I fix those performance issues?
Every 1-10 seconds a Player dies/kills someone, so then it has to update the table.

Comment: It's quite simple to paste code here. You paste it, select it, and hit Ctrl-K (or press the `{}' code toolbar button).

Comment: This needs to be narrowed down some to figure out the cause. If you disable the plugin, does that fix the performance problem?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks for your quick responses

Comment: I'll bet you are reconnecting to MySQL 20 times a second?  That is about the limit (depending OS and other things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a PreparedStatement only improves performance if you using bind variables for the dynamic portion of the content.

For example:

```
PreparedStatement x = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM FFA WHERE Spielername = 
'"+ Spielername + "';");
```

Should be changed to:

```
PreparedStatement x = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM FFA WHERE Spielername = ?;");
x.setString(1, Spielername);
```

Your current use of PreparedStatements is likely actually slower than just executing your statement directly.

Additionally, your updates should use PreparedStatements also. Here is another example:

```
x.executeUpdate("UPDATE FFA SET Tode = '" + punkte
                 + "' WHERE Spielername = '" + Spielername + "'");
```

Should be changed to:

```
PreparedStatment pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE FFA SET Tode = ?"
    + " WHERE Spielername = ?");
pStmt.setString(1, punkte);
pStmt.setString(2, Spielername);
pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thank you! The performance increase was big :D

I think the problem now really is fixed

Comment: @Vinci if this is the answer, please mark it as such.